# Phoenix: Render content_tag as HTML?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Following along with this [Jose Valim](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/09/dynamic-forms-with-phoenix/) post, I end up with a nested tuple of HTML information from the call to `#content_tag`.

```
{:safe,
 [60, "div", " class=\"form-group \"", 62,
  [[60, "label", " class=\"control-label\" for=\"_username\"", 62, "Username",
    60, 47, "label", 62],
   [60, "textarea",
    " class=\"form-control\" id=\"_username\" name=\"[username]\"", 62,
    ["\n", "username"], 60, 47, "textarea", 62], ""], 60, 47, "div", 62]}
```

I would like to write a test to check the output, but I would rather check the generated HTML than the nested tuples. How can I render this result into HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Phoenix.HTML.Safe.to_iodata` and `IO.iodata_to_binary` to convert that to a String:

```
iex(1)> raw = {:safe,
...(1)>  [60, "div", " class=\"form-group \"", 62,
...(1)>   [[60, "label", " class=\"control-label\" for=\"_username\"", 62, "Username",
...(1)>     60, 47, "label", 62],
...(1)>    [60, "textarea",
...(1)>     " class=\"form-control\" id=\"_username\" name=\"[username]\"", 62,
...(1)>     ["\n", "username"], 60, 47, "textarea", 62], ""], 60, 47, "div", 62]}
iex(2)> raw |> Phoenix.HTML.Safe.to_iodata |> IO.iodata_to_binary |> IO.puts
<div class="form-group "><label class="control-label" for="_username">Username</label><textarea class="form-control" id="_username" name="[username]">
username</textarea></div>
```

Comment: Now there's also `Phoenix.HTML.safe_to_string/1`